# Paging in Crystal Sub report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working on VS 2005 / Crystal Reports.

In the Sub report, i need to limit to 18 records per page.

I need to do paging for the Crystal Sub Report ?

I am not able to do paging for crystal sub reports ..!

Comment: In the Details section of your report, there is a property called "Format with multiple columns".  It lets you display more than 1 record on a single row. This might solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress the detail section with this condition:

```
if recordnumber>N then true else false

// N being the number of rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Paging is handled by the main report.

Why do you need to restrict the subreport output to 18 rows per page?

Comment: In Main report - Page 1 ( front side ) i can have 9 records and in Page 2 ( Back Side ) i can 9 records .. in total for sheet 1 - i am able to hold 18 records.


In case if we have around 40 records, we need to go for 3 sheets.

Our sub report is actually the selected columns of Main Report. Sub Report has two fields - Like Name / Department.

When we have 40 records, It tries to display all 40 in the sub report ... but we are able to view maximum of 25 records ...  and its duplicating with other sheets ..

Comment: I don't know of an easy way to do this - it sounds as though you should set a maximum of 25 records to be returned in the subreport (for example, by using top N processing or conditional row suppression in the subreport), but then you would lose the remaining records from the subreport.

Comment: At present, i have set the maximum of 25 records in the Sub Report. I am omitting the remaining records

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways.  Create a Shared variable

shared numbervar count := 0;

Increment the count variable in a formula.  Place the formula in the details section and suppress it.

Conditionally suppress the Details section when the count variable is > 18.